# How to get MongoDB ObjectID as hex string into the renderer

Tags: javascript, mongodb, electron, ipc, objectid

I'm missing something here. I want the hex string in the renderer. So I wrote a Mongo Util function that returns the hex string. That works fine. Then I wrote a handler / invoke pair to pass the object and return the hex string. The handler does receive the hex string. But at the renderer, I see the object back.

How to get the hex string at the renderer?

```
//main.js
ipcMain.handle('ObjectIDtoHexString', async (event,args) => {
  const result = mongoUtil.ObjectIDtoHexString(args)
  console.log(result) //as string
  return result
})


//renderer.js
console.log(JSON.parse(data.value)) //as Object
ipcRenderer.invoke('ObjectIDtoHexString', JSON.parse(data.value)).then(console.log) //as object ??


//mongoUtil.js
const { ObjectID } = require( 'mongodb' )

function ObjectIDtoHexString (object) {
  let hexString = ''
  Object.values(object.id).forEach(elem =>{
    const result = elem.toString(16)
    if(result.length === 2) {
      hexString += result
    } else {
      hexString += "0" + result
    }
  })
  const id = new ObjectID(hexString)
  console.log(id) //as string
  return id   
}
```

Comment: Your `ObjectIDtoHexString` converts object id to hex string and then creates an object id from the hex string. Return `hexString`.

Comment: Thank you D. SM that indeed solved the issue.